# Can I apply for Korean travel visa from Japan?

Tags: visas, japan, south-korea

I’m a Mongolian citizen currently on a travel visa in Japan. Am I allowed to apply for a travel visa directly from Tokyo or must I return home and then apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must apply from Mongolia (or from another country that you have permanent residency). You cannot apply from Japan, as one of the requirements for the visa application is:

> Japanese resident card must remain valid for more than 3 months

You can find our more at [the official website](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/jp-ko/wpge/m_20079/contents.do) of the Korean Embassy in Japan.